# ArcGIS 10.x Create equidistant polyline that are perpendicular to an axis

Tags: arcgis-10.0, line

I have a polyline that represents a cyclone track and I want to create equidistant polyline that are perpendicular to the cyclone track.

Comment: Don't you want the "equidistant polyline" to be *parallel*?  Anything "perpendicular" to the track surely won't be equidistant from the track!

Comment: Yea, as whuber said, you can draw equidistant polylines paralel to the track/stream/line. You can try and implement HEC-RAS's "Construct XS Cut Lines Tool" for your application/problem/track.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an ArcInfo license, you can use the `line_side` parameter of the [Buffer (Analysis)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000019000000.htm) tool. This will give you a parallel curve on the `LEFT`, or `RIGHT` side of your cyclone track that is offset by your buffer distance.

If you don't have ArcInfo, there are plenty of open source options to choose from that also do this:

- JTS - [Single-sided buffer](http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2010/11/single-sided-buffers-in-jts.html)
- GEOS - [setSingleSided](http://geos.osgeo.org/doxygen/classgeos_1_1operation_1_1buffer_1_1BufferOp.html)
- Shapely - [LineString.parallel_offset](https://github.com/sgillies/shapely/blob/master/shapely/geometry/linestring.py#L83)
- PostGIS - [ST_OffsetCurve](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/ST_OffsetCurve.html)